# How to make sense of the $y$-axis values of a binomial distribution that approximates a normal distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

[image]

I would like to understand this picture better. From what I've gathered, normal distribution is important because of the central limit theorem. This picture shows that we can approximate a binomial distribution curve with a normal distribution curve given enough trials. I have two questions: First, how is the central limit theorem illustrated here when there aren't any 'means' plotted? Second: How is the probability density of 50 heads approximately .06? Why wouldn't it be .5? Thank you advance. I am a beginner at stats and am just learning the basics.

Comment: Why on earth would the probability of exactly $50$ heads be $\frac12$?

Answer (score 2):

I believe central limit theorem says that sum of many independent random variables is approximately normally distributed. So since binomial is sum of 100 independent bernoulli random variables with p=.5, their distribution will be approximated by normal distribution. So what you are seeing in the picture is one trial of 100 tosses, then plot a point. Repeat this many, many times and you will generate your histogram.

The probability of a head on a single toss is .5, but surely you know that the probability of 50 heads in 100 tosses is given by the formula

$$\Pr(X=50)={100\choose 50}.5^{50}(1-.5)^{100-50}=0.07958924$$

You might say whoa this is so small we want to expect around 50 heads.

It is true, if we let $X$ be between about 40 to 60 heads ($50\pm10$) we find that the probability is

$$\sum_{i=40}^{60}{100\choose i}.5^i(1-.5)^{100-i}=0.9647998$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So as the tosses increase, this curve should look more 'normal'? Or do we have to increase the number of trials, too?

Comment: @user873295 The process that Stacker describes (plot a point for each trial to build the histogram) would generate a frequency histogram where the vertical axis counts numbers of trials. The histogram here is a *relative* frequency histogram which basically is the same but divides by the number of trials. As far as I can tell, the histogram in your picture is the "true" distribution, i.e. what you'd obtain if you did many many 100-toss trials. The CLT is not about this aspect; it says that this "true" histogram gets more normal with the number of tosses. With n=100, it is already quite normal.

Comment: @user873295 There is a threshold for the central limit theorem to apply, you need at least 20-30 tosses per trial (I think. There might be more detailed criteria than this.) So if this criteria is met, plotting enough points on the histogram will be approximately normal. But the limiting histogram will be more approximately normal if the number of tosses per trial is greater, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

1. The binomial distribution here is actually a sum of Bernoulli($1/2$) random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_{100}$ (where $X_i$ is $1$ if the $i$th flip is heads, and zero otherwise). The Central Limit Theorem implies that the distribution of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{100}} \sum_{i=1}^{100} (X_i - 1/2)$ is approximately normal with mean $0$ and variance $1/4$. If we multiply this by $\sqrt{100}$ and add $50$, we get your binomial random variable $\sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i$, which is approximately normal with mean $50$ and variance $12.5$.
2. The probability of *exactly* 50 heads is $\binom{100}{50} \frac{1}{2^{100}}$, which is quite small. You are probably thinking of the probability of *at most* 50 heads, which is indeed $1/2$.

Comment: There is an error here, dividing by 10 will not get the mean down to 1/2 from 50. Actually there is a shift *and* scaling in the CLT, you cannot adjust both the mean and variance by a scaling alone since they don't scale the same with n.

Comment: @Ian Oops, thanks for catching that.